# Window does not close when Python script on Windows is finished, until launched program exits

Tags: python, shell, exit

The follwing python script works fine, exept that the shell window remains open.

```
file = open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\SteelUsage.bsu", "a+")
input = raw_input("Please enter project name:")
input = input.upper ()
for line in file.readlines():
        if input in line:
            print "Project name already exists, executing BadePanel"
            import time
            time.sleep(4)
            import subprocess
            subprocess.call(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
            exit(subprocess)
file.write (input+"\n")
print "Project name written to file, executing BadePanel"
import time
time.sleep(4)
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
exit(subprocess)
file.close()
```

The shell window terminates ony after i close the exeuted progrm (BadePanel.exe)
I would like the script to display the printed text in the shell window, wait 4 secs, execute the program, and then exit.
Thanks

Comment: 1) provide a *minimal* example 2) read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> subprocess.call()
>
> > Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

So the `.call()` function only ever returns after BadePanael.exe finishes.

Instead, try:

```
print "Project name written to file, executing BadePanel"
time.sleep(4)
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
sys.exit(0)
```